# Transaction rollback error

Tags: c#, ado.net

I am using a ado.net helper class from [Here](http://www.blackbeltcoder.com/Articles/ado/an-ado-net-sql-helper-class). I don't know how to use transaction using the helper. Below is the code I have tried. Am I doing the right thing? I always hit the `This SqlTransaction has completed; it is no longer usable.` error.

```
            Adodb.ConnectionString = "...";

            Adodb db = new Adodb(); 
            SqlTransaction trans = db.BeginTransaction();

            try
            {
                string qry = "UPDATE PSCHCounter SET SeqNo = '0' WHERE CountID = 'PCSTL'";
                db.ExecNonQuery(qry);
                string qry1 = "UPDATE PSCHCounter SET SeqNo = '1' WHERE CountID = 'GJNLP'";
                db.ExecNonQuery(qry1);

                // Commit 
                trans.Commit();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                try
                {
                    // Rollback
                    trans.Rollback();
                    // Log exception
                }
                catch (Exception ex2)
                {
                    // Log exception
                }
            }
            finally
            {
                // Close db connection
                db.Dispose();
            }
```

Thank you.

Comment: Any other good database helper to recommend?

Comment: There is the MS Enterprise Library, but that has a much steeper learning curve. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff648951.aspx

Comment: @mgnoonan Thanks. Need something fast and easy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is you are calling `trans.Commit()` instead of `db.Commit()`. This worked for me:

```
    AdoHelper.ConnectionString = "...";

    using (AdoHelper db = new AdoHelper())
    {
        // Start the transaction
        db.BeginTransaction();

        try
        {
            db.ExecNonQuery("UPDATE FeedItems SET Title = 'Test3' WHERE Id = 456");
            db.ExecNonQuery("UPDATE FeedItems SET Title = 'Test4' WHERE Id = 457");

            // Commit  
            db.Commit();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            db.Rollback();
        }
    }
```

Comment: My apologies, I completely skipped over the first sentence. I will take a look and revise my answer.

Comment: Seems like a bug, or maybe a usage issue. The transaction does complete successfully (my data is updated), but I get the exception as well.